# How is the "frosted glass effect" on apple.com implemented?

Tags: css

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FibA.jpg) is here.

---

Is this implemented with css3 or other technique? And how?

Thanks!

---

Actually I'd like to know how APPLE is implementing this. :-)

Comment: Use the same `background-image` and `background-size` on the `body` and a `:before` pseudo element for the bottom bar with `background-position: 0 100%` on both, then apply a blur filter for the pseudo-element. At least that's how I'd do it.

Comment: @Ana Thanks! I found out the answer too.

Comment: Did a demo and turned this into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

### 2024 answer

We can use `backdrop-filter` for glassmorphism effects.

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='bar'></div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.bar {
  background: #fff1;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px)
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0 }

html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
  background: 
    url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462556791646-c201b8241a94?w=1400) 
      50%/ cover
}

.bar {
  align-self: end;
  background: #fff1;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px)
}

/* prettifying styles */
.bar, ul { display: flex }

.bar {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: .5em;
  color: #fff;
  font: 1.125em Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif
}

ul { gap: 1em }

li { list-style: none }
```

```html
<div class='bar'>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☼</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### original answer, preserved for web history reasons

Use the same `background-image` on the `html` (or `body`) element and a `:before` pseudo element for the bottom bar with `background-position: 50% 100%` on both, then apply a blur filter for the pseudo-element. At least that's how I'd do it.

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='bar'></div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
html, .bar:before {
  height: 100%;
  background: black url(image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
.bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  height: 5em;
}
.bar:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  content: '';
}
```

```css
html, .bar:before {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background: black 
    url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462556791646-c201b8241a94?w=1400) 
    50% 100% no-repeat
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(192, 192, 192, .1);
  font: 1.125em Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif
}

.bar:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  content: ''
}

/* prettify bar content */
.bar h1 { float: left }

.bar ul, .bar li {
    float: right;
    list-style: none
}

.bar li { margin: 1em }
```

```html
<div class='bar'>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☼</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
    <li>☀</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<svg width='0' height='0'>
    <filter id='blur'>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='5'/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep, I'm with Ana on the approach (I like the use of the pseudo-element - clever!)

It's worthwhile noting that [you can make the filter effect cross-browser](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur), since the CSS3 is derived from SVG, and MS did their own weird proprietary version ages ago. [You can even animate it.](http://demosthenes.info/blog/665/Animated-Inset-Captions-With-Filtered-Backgrounds)

Comment: I've read about the `filter: url()` thing before, but never actually tried it. One thing to be noted about supporting IE9 and older is that an actual element, not a pseudo, would be needed for that, as those old IE filters don't work on pseudo-elements. I think I'd add that element using a conditional comment just for IE9 and older and have the same styles for it as for the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2):

On that particular page, Apple are achieving the effect by using a copy of the background image which has been blurred and made opaque.

However, a similar effect can be achieved using the [CSS3 filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) - although this property has yet to be widely adopted.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use css Opacity property, and put image there.Nwm, its just image that being cutted and then putted back.